# Extend slack bot menu color bar across full message (node, slack block kit, slack api)

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I have a slack bot that uses a menu drop down, and it has a color bar on the side.
See the screenshot of what I have
[here in the green circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfXvh.png)

I want the bar to extend the whole message [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToOv5.png)
Note: This image is edited to show the example of the red bar (and because the actual slack bot message isn't important)

My code has something like

```
    let slackPost = {
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": myText
                }
            } // ... some other blocks
        ],
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": menuTitle,
                "color": menuBarColor,
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": menuName,
                        "text": menuPlaceHolder,
                        "type": "select",
                        "options": menuOptions   
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

The new slack blocks layout doesn't allow the old `color` attachments property. You can find official documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/messaging/attachments-to-blocks#direct_equivalents).

> There is one exception, and that's the color parameter, which currently does not have a block alternative. If you are strongly attached () to the color bar, use the blocks parameter within an attachment.

Answer (score 8):

You can nest blocks inside the attachment property, like this:

```
let slackPost = {
  "attachments": [{
    "color": message.color,
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": myText
        }
      } // ... some other blocks
    ]
   }]
```

Comment: This works for RGB colors (`#439FE0`), but afaict named colors (`good`, `warning`, `danger`) show up as grey when blocks are present inside an attachment.